# JSF populate request payload only with changed fileds

Tags: jsf

I have service call that which expects only the changed value to be send in the payload ex if out of 5 fields only one is chnaged then request would be :

{
field 1: "qwert"
}

My problem is how do I  track which fields have been changed in the form so that I send only those fields ahead.

Comment: What is a 'patch call' and on the server side **you** know what actually changed or not, so your question is sort of too broad and hence vague.

Comment: Have re edited my question hope that makes sense.

Comment: It's only possible when you use Ajax and modify the jsf.ajax.request and/or whatever ajax library of the JSF component library being used (e.g. jQuery in PrimeFaces).

Comment: Wouldn't it be more easy to check that in the server in a bean before calling the service?

Comment: yes thats what I am currently trying to do